# explode an array php not working

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I don't understant why my explode doesn't work :

I have an array :

```
array(6) { 
[0]=> string(0) "" 
[1]=> string(21) " Subject Hello World " 
[2]=> string(57) " Bonjour se jserais base sdf sdf sd f sqdf qsfd " 
[3]=> string(22) " martial@gironde.com2 " 
[4]=> string(12) " hello byee " 
[5]=> string(11) " loul fund " }
```

I want to creat an another tab for element 4 an 5. I try an

```
$one = explode(" ", $this->connect[4]);
var_dump($one);
```

But the result is :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " hello byee " }
```

and not :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "hello" [1]=>string(4) "byee" }
```

Do you no why ?

Comment: Technically your array should consist of 4 elements because you have two spaces surrounding each string. Use `trim()` to remove those.

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($this->connect[4]);` ?

Comment: The result is string(12) " hello byee ". I use trim() to @silkfire, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are those spaces in the string or some other form of white space?

Comment: Tim most likely nailed it.

Comment: Most probably those space characters (ASCII code 0x20 (dec 32)) aren't really space characters but something else. Maybe an NBSP?

Comment: What is the result of `echo ord(substr($this->connect[4],0,1));`

Comment: just for fun, if you want to be sure it is indeed not a space, just do "var_dump(ord($this->connect[4][0]));" I am guessing it will not say it is "32"

Comment: Unexpected. that is actually a linefeed. Not any type of whitespace.

Comment: yep, i use **'/\s+/'**, thx for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this

```
  $parts = preg_split('/\s+/',$this->connect[4]);
  print_r($parts);
```

Comment: $parts = preg_split('/\s+/',trim($this->connect[4])); work ! :) Don't understand why explode not... an idea ?

Comment: @MartialE the one which you have used is also working for me thats why i have given you alternate solution.

Comment: @MartialE `\s` matches any whitespace character. It must have been some sort of other whitespace character.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ there is a function to see the special character?

Comment: echo ord($this->connect[4]); say **10**

Comment: @MartialE if you use `ord()` you can check the values against an ASCII table. http://www.asciitable.com/. **10** is a new line character.

Comment: well, ord() i very usefull ! thx, now i understand why it doesn't work. And why **'/\s+/'** work :)

Comment: Thus, MartialE, in this case, `explode("\n", $this->connect[4])` would have worked =)

Answer (score 1):

Working example at http://codepad.org/0uMXe9Js.

```
<?php
$connect = array(
    '',
    ' Subject Hello World ',
    ' Bonjour se jserais base sdf sdf sd f sqdf qsfd ',
    ' martial@gironde.com2 ',
    ' hello byee ',
    ' loul fund '
);

print_r(explode(' ', $connect[4]));
print_r(explode(' ' , trim($connect[4])));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => hello
    [2] => byee
    [3] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => byee
)
```

The problem must be in your array values, are you sure those are really spaces? Use [PHP ord function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to check them out.

Comment: well like @Praveen kalal say, i use an alternative **'/\s+/'**